# How much money to buy commodities?

Tags: commodities

Just like for most stock brokers ask for minimum deposits starting at $1000, What is the minimum monetary ammount to invest in commodities markets such as NYMEX, CBOT or CME?

Comment: In general, or did you have one in mind? Pork Bellies may have different initial margins than, say, gold.

Comment: In general, assuming I don't know yet which commodities I'll be investing in. @JoeTaxpayer

Comment: Keep in mind that when holding a futures position, you need to maintain the two different types of margin - the initial margin and the variation margin.  So, you may need to put up $4200 initial margin for a crude oil contract, but if the price moves against you, then you will need to cover the variation.  If you don't have funds on account, then you will be called for additional margin.  The high degree of leveraging that goes with futures contracts means that the variation margin can add up quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link only answers aren't good, but [the list](https://www.efutures.com/traders/contract_specs.php) is pretty long. It's a moving target, the requirement change based on a number of criteria. It usually jumps to force you to sell when you hold a losing position, or when your commodity is about to skyrocket.